# What is cold-start penalty ? What are some ways to reduce it?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

when a new process is created using a fork() function, there is a cold start penalty, what is this and why does it happen?

Comment: Nice one. Where did this question come up, what have been topics lately?

Comment: I was reading up on multi threading and wondered about using processes instead, my professor just told me that new processes have a cold start penalty but dint go into detail.

Comment: I see. Given `fork()`'s *shared state* approach, caches all over the memory hierarchy come to mind, starting with address translation. A common combinations seems to be virtually addressed L1 caches with physically addressed L2 (&up), lest it gets too easily comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

"Cold start penalty" is the penalty for starting a process that has never run. The operating system has to read the code from disk, page tables have to be set up, caches filled in as instructions are executed/data fetched, and so on. If the process has run before, some of the above will already have been set up (and perhaps not fully evicted).

Comment: `penalty for starting a process that has never run` even rephrased as *a program that has no traces of execution left in the non-permanent machine state*, that would apply to a (*fork*-) *exec*. I take a *fork* to create a clone of a process, identical from the inside but for the *process id* returned by *fork*. And it *does* have a start penalty, different from that of another thread. And I think it *debatable* to use *cold* in this context.